# Show $\sigma_{X}^{2}(t)=\begin{cases} x_{0}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}e^{\alpha t}[e^{\alpha t}-1], & \alpha \neq 0\\ x_{0}\beta t, & \alpha = 0 \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, improper-integrals, stochastic-calculus

I have some difficulties in finding :
$\sigma_{X}^{2}(t)=\begin{cases} x_{0}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}e^{\alpha t}[e^{\alpha t}-1], & \alpha \neq 0\\
x_{0}\beta t, & \alpha = 0
\end{cases}$

Could you please elaborate on the calculation that led to it?

> [from **An Introduction to Stochastic Processes with Applications to Biology**, by Linda J. S. Allen, 2010, p. 368]
>
> The mean and variance can be written as
> $$\mu_X(t)=\int_0^\infty x p(x,t)\,dx$$
> and
> $$\sigma^2_X(t)=\int_0^\infty x^2p(x,t)\,dx-\mu^2_X(t),$$
> with intial conditions $\mu_x(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\delta(x-x_0)=x_0$ and $\sigma^2_X(0)=0.$
>
> Applying the forward Kolmogorov equation $(8.16),$ then
>
> $$\begin{align}{d\mu_X\over dt}&={d\over dt}\int_0^\infty xp(x,t)\,dx=\int_0^\infty x{\partial p\over \partial t}dx\\
> &=\int_0^\infty\left[-\alpha x{\partial(xp)\over\partial x}+{1\over 2}\beta x{\partial^2(xp)\over\partial x^2} \right]\,dx\\
> &=-\alpha x^2p(x,t)\big|_0^\infty+\alpha\int_0^\infty xp(x,t)\,dx\\
> &\quad +{1\over 2}\beta x{\partial(xp)\over\partial x}\bigg|_0^\infty-{1\over 2}\beta\int_0^\infty{\partial(xp)\over\partial x}\,dx\\
> &=\alpha\int_0^\infty xp(x,t)\,dx.
> \end{align}$$
>
> Thus, $${d\mu_X\over dt}=\alpha\mu_x(t).$$
>
> In the preceding derivation it was assumed that
>
> $$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}x^2{\partial p(x,t)\over\partial x}=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}x^2p(x,t)=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}x p(x,t)=0,$$
>
> which follows from the existence of the mean and variance of $X(t).$ The solution of the differential equation for the mean $\mu_X(t)$ with $\mu_X(0)=x_0$ is
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid orange]{\mu_X(t)=x_0e^{\alpha t}.}$$
>
> The mean grows exponentially if $\alpha>0.$ The variance is equal to
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid orange]{\sigma^2_X(t)=\begin{cases}x_0{\beta\over\alpha}e^{\alpha t}[e^{\alpha t}-1]&\alpha\ne 0\\
> x_0\beta t&\alpha=0.\end{cases}}$$

Comment: I believe, @Don freecss missed some important part about what is $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: @Don I've replaced the pictures with MathJax (and fixed an obviously-omitted factor of $e^{\alpha t}$ in your MathJax equation for the variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That result is for a time-homogeneous diffusion process $\{X(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$ such that $X(0)=x_0$, with *linear* infinitesimal mean and variance ($\alpha x$ and $\beta x$, respectively); then the pdf $p(x,t)$ satisfies the forward Kolmogorov equation:
$$\partial_t\,p=-\alpha\,\partial_x(x\,p)+{1\over 2}\beta\,\partial^2_x(x\,p),
$$
so $\sigma^2_X(t)$ must satisfy the following differential equation, where $\mu_X(t)=x_0\,e^{\alpha t}$:
$$\begin{align}D_t\,\sigma^2_X(t)
&=D_t\left(\int_0^\infty x^2\,p\,dx -\mu^2_X(t)\right)\\[2ex]
&=\int_0^\infty x^2\,\partial_tp\,dx -2\alpha\mu^2_X(t)\\[2ex]
&=-\alpha\int_0^\infty x^2\partial_x(x\,p)\,dx+{1\over 2}\beta \int_0^\infty x^2\partial^2_x(x\,p)\,dx - 2\alpha\mu^2_X(t)\\[2ex]
&=-\alpha\left(\left[x^3p\right]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty2x^2p\,dx  \right) \\
&\quad+{1\over 2}\beta\left(\left[x^2\partial_x(xp)\right]_0^\infty- \int_0^\infty  2x\partial_x(xp)dx\right)-2\alpha\mu^2_X(t)\\[2ex]
&=2\alpha\left(\int_0^\infty x^2p\,dx  \right) 
-\beta\left(\int_0^\infty  x\partial_x(xp)dx\right)-2\alpha\mu^2_X(t)\\[2ex]
&=2\alpha\left(\sigma^2_X(t)+\mu^2_X(t) \right) 
-\beta\left(\left[x^2p\right]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty  xp\,dx\right)-2\alpha\mu^2_X(t)\\[2ex]
&=2\alpha\left(\sigma^2_X(t)+\mu^2_X(t) \right) 
+\beta\mu_X(t)-2\alpha\mu^2_X(t)\\[2ex]
\color{blue}{D_t\,\sigma^2_X(t)}&=\color{blue}{2\alpha\,\sigma^2_X(t)+x_0\beta\,e^{\alpha t}}\tag{Eq.1}
\end{align}$$
where we have repeatedly applied integration by parts, and have assumed that  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^kp(x,t)=0$ for $k=1,2,3,$ and also that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^2\partial_xp(x,t)=0.$

It is now readily verified that Eq.1 is satisfied by the stated solution:
$$\sigma^2_X(t)=\begin{cases}x_0{\beta\over\alpha}e^{\alpha t}(e^{\alpha t}-1)&\alpha\ne 0\\
x_0\beta t&\alpha=0.\end{cases}$$

---

**NB**: Eq.1 is a simple nonhomogeneous linear first-order ordinary differential equation; consequently, rather than just verifying the stated solution, it's straightforward to obtain it directly by [standard methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations), letting $y(t)=\sigma^2_X(t):$

If $\alpha=0$ then Eq.1 is just $y'=x_0 \beta.$ Integration then gives $y=x_0\beta t+c,$ and the initial condition $y(0)=0$ (because $V[X(0)]=V[x_0]=0$) then requires $c=0;$ hence, the solution is $y=x_0\beta t.$

If $\alpha\ne 0$ then apply the standard methods:

1. Put Eq.1 into standard form: $$y'+Py=Q$$ where $P=-2\alpha,\ Q=x_0\beta e^{\alpha t}.$
2. Find the integrating factor: $e^{\int P\,dt} = e^{Pt}$.
3. Multiply both sides of Eq.1 by the integrating factor, rearrange, and integrate:
   $$\begin{align}y'e^{Pt}+Pye^{Pt}&=Qe^{Pt}\\
   \therefore\quad (ye^{Pt})'&=Qe^{Pt}\\
   \therefore\quad ye^{Pt}&=\int Qe^{Pt}\,dt+c\\
   &=\beta x_0\int e^{(\alpha+P)t}\,dt+c \\
   &={\beta x_0\over \alpha+P}e^{(\alpha+P)t}+c
   \end{align}$$
4. Apply the initial condition $y(0)=0$ to find $c=x_0{\beta\over \alpha},$ and rearrange to find
   $$y=x_0{\beta\over\alpha}e^{\alpha t}(e^{\alpha t}-1).$$

Comment: I'm using the notation $D_t={d\over dt},\ \partial_x={\partial\over\partial x},$ etc.

Comment: Really appreciated. Please, Could you elaborate more about why $${d\over dt}\,(\sigma^2_X(t))=2\alpha(\sigma^2_X(t))+\beta x_0 e^{\alpha t}\implies \sigma^2_X(t)=\begin{cases}x_0{\beta\over\alpha}e^{\alpha t}(e^{\alpha t}-1)&\alpha\ne 0\\
x_0\beta t&\alpha=0.\end{cases}$$
Please, could you give me the kind of this differential equation (${d\over dt}\,(\sigma^2_X(t))=2\alpha(\sigma^2_X(t))+\beta x_0 e^{\alpha t}$) that leads to that kind of solution. I'm still looking in Rudin to see if there is any differential equation to looks like the above one.

Comment: @Donfreecss This is a first-order nonhomogeneous linear ordinary differential equation, i.e. it can be put into standard form $y′+Py=Q$ and solved by standard methods, which I've added to my answer.

Comment: really apperciated